# Unable to Click on Edit Button , in WebTable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am using xpath to click on edit button , but i dont know where the webtable starts so i can click on the webelement.
Below is the link for WebTable.

http://demo.automationtesting.in/WebTable.html

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What XPath did you use to click on the edit button?

Comment: which element u want to click specify

Comment: code trials please ?

Comment: I have used Xpath //*[@id="1530159138916-0-uiGrid-000B-cell"]/user-click-select/div[1]/button

Comment: I want to click on the edit button, with pencil logo.

Comment: Below is the code,  WebElement Edit_btn= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//user-click-select/div[1]/button"));
  Actions action = new Actions(driver).doubleClick(Edit_btn);
  action.build().perform();

Comment: you mean first edit button ?

Comment: Yes, the first edit button

Comment: Hi Friends, can u help on this..thanks :)

Comment: @Varun.S To improve quality of your Question, Please add sample HTML block and your trail code. Link might can be loss in future. And User will be not able to find.

Comment: Sure, I will improve from next post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// gets the first edit button
WebElement Edit_btn= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'avddbl']/button")).get(0); 
Actions action = new Actions(driver).doubleClick(Edit_btn); 
action.build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want some specific selection e.g. want to edit info of particular user
Then you can use below xpath where you have to changes email address only it will click on the edit icon of that particular record .

```
//div[text()='steven@hotm.com']/../following-sibling::div//div[@class='avddbl']/button[contains(@class,'btn')]
```